xshift doesn't work for \draw inside remember picture,overlay tikzpicture
I want to insert a booktab drawing to every page in a document. For that I am using a tikzpicture with remember picture,overlay option, and a \AddToHook{shipout/background} so that the tikz drawing will be printed on every page.
I am trying to move the booktab to the left using xshift= but I don't see any effect. Why?
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1in}
  \put(\dimexpr-\hoffset\relax,\dimexpr-\paperheight+\voffset\relax){%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path [fill=red,xshift=20pt]%% <<-- no xshift
     (current page.north)--++(0,-2)--++(140:1)--++(-140:1)--++(0,2)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}



You can shift the coordinate:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \path [fill=red] ([xshift=20pt]current page.north)--++(0,-2)--++(140:1)--++(-140:1)--++(0,2)--cycle;
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
text
\end{document}

Or you can transform the canvas:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=20pt}]
    \path [fill=red] (current page.north)--++(0,-2)--++(140:1)--++(-140:1)--++(0,2)--cycle;
  \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}



Can you tell me why \path [xshift=20pt] doesn't work?

@tush  You are using an absolute coordinate in the path. It will still be at the absolute location.
